# How to perform point to raster operation and plot it with raster of different spatial resolution in R?

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-sp

I have following dataframe with three columns namely, "Latitude", "Longitude", and "value", along with a raster file (as attached with name "ras.tif') and area shape file (as attached with name "okl_shape.shp"):

## Dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Latitude=c(34.80833, 34.79851, 34.91418, 36.07204, 36.80253, 35.96305, 
36.69256, 36.83129, 35.5915, 34.8497, 34.60896, 35.65282, 36.74813, 35.54615, 33.92075, 
35.54848, 35.20494, 36.26353, 36.84053, 36.60183), Longitude=c(-98.02325, -96.66909, -98.29216, 
-99.90308, -100.53012, -95.86621, -102.49713, -99.64101, -99.27059, -97.0033, -96.33309, 
-96.80407, -98.36274, -99.7279, -96.32027, -98.03654, -99.80344, -98.49766, -96.42777, -101.6013 
), value=c(0.84629845, NA, 0.916147287, 0.735707364, 0.432443798, 0.959728682, 0.123924419, 
0.849589147, 0.307998062, 0.932215116, 0.939897287, 0.915825581, NA, 0.273945736, NA, 
0.705023256, 0.447494186, 0.840686047, 0.901098837, 0.202523256))
```

## Attached files

Here is the shape file of my area:
[file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyp6zkyky69g4b4/okl_shape.shp?dl=0)
Here is the raster file:
[file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfu6lj318z0ts8z/ras.tif?dl=0)

## Problem Description

I have to make a plot comparing point data (i.e. data frame described above) with attached raster (i.e. "ras.tif") and the shape file should overlay these plots. See the picture below for reference (In this figure, the left panel plots the points values as defined in the dataframe, right panel plots the raster, and the polygon represent the area shape file):
[image]

## My code

I tried solving this with "spplot" but couldn't get the desired plot (something similar to above plot). Also, I don't know how can I insert the shape file in my plot. Below is the code I tried so far:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(maptools)
meso.shape <- st_read('okl_shape.shp')
ras1 <- raster('ras.tif')
df <- data.frame(Latitude=c(34.80833, 34.79851, 34.91418, 36.07204, 36.80253, 35.96305, 
36.69256, 36.83129, 35.5915, 34.8497, 34.60896, 35.65282, 36.74813, 35.54615, 33.92075, 
35.54848, 35.20494, 36.26353, 36.84053, 36.60183
), Longitude=c(-98.02325, -96.66909, -98.29216, -99.90308, -100.53012, -95.86621, -102.49713, 
-99.64101, -99.27059, -97.0033, -96.33309, -96.80407, -98.36274, -99.7279, -96.32027, -98.03654, 
-99.80344, -98.49766, -96.42777, -101.6013), value=c(0.84629845, NA, 0.916147287, 0.735707364, 
0.432443798, 0.959728682, 0.123924419, 0.849589147, 0.307998062, 0.932215116, 0.939897287, 
0.915825581, NA, 0.273945736, NA, 0.705023256, 0.447494186, 0.840686047, 0.901098837, 
0.202523256))
coordinates(df) <- ~Longitude+Latitude
x <- vect2rast(df, fname = names(df)[1])
x <- raster(x)
extent(x) <- extent(ras1)
crs(x) <- crs(ras1)
x <- projectRaster(x,ras1)
s <- stack(ras1,x)
sp <- as(s, 'SpatialPolygons')
p <- spplot(s, names.attr = c("Simulated FWI","Observed FWI"))
show(p)
```